# How to download a note with a specific title using "FindNotesMetadata"

Tags: vb.net, evernote-app-notebook

i want to download a note with a title,for example,"170222". this is my code:

```
    Dim myfilter As New NoteFilter
     myfilter.Words("intitle:170222")
    Dim myspc As NotesMetadataResultSpec
    '?Specialized.
    Dim myResultsList As NotesMetadataList = store.FindNotesMetadata(myfilter, 0, 500, myspc)
```

the error line:"myfilter.Words("intitle:170222")"
the error message:"属性访问必须分配给属性或使用属性值"

please help,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm stupid, I'm ashamed！
this is a so easy question.
the correct code is:

```
myfilter.Words="intitle:170222"
```